# How to make frame-by-frame animation in fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

How to make frame-by-frame animation in fabric.js? for example 100 frames in PNG format. How to change frames with javascript, in my loop function?

```
var imagesFrame = []; //frame images (images are already loaded from server)
// Array element = new Image()

function loopAnim(){
 //change(update) frame in Fabric.Image
}
```